# Why nginx add some chars at the top of js file

Tags: zend-framework, nginx, ckeditor

I have a zend application running into Nginx server.  When I call `ckeditor` js I get somthing like this :

```
SyntaxError: illegal character
[Stopper sur une erreur]    

О╩©/*

ckeditor.js (line 1, col 1)
```

Knowing that the file `ckeditor.js` is proper and I use it into another application running into Apache server.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a BOM, Byte Order Mark, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark.

Fix would be to either remove it from the file (assuming the file in UTF-8), or, if your app is able to handle UTF-8 with BOMs, to ask nginx to mark the response as being in UTF-8 by using [charset](http://nginx.org/r/charset) directive:

```
charset utf-8;
```